# Sprite rotation facing mouse stops working when map scrolls

Tags: python, pygame

I have implemented a rotation for the player sprite so it faces the mouse, but when I move outside of the original window and the 'camera' starts moving, the rotation stops working.

Here is my code for player rotation:

```
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, x, y):
    pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
    self.image.fill(WHITE)
    self.orig_img = self.image
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
    self.vel = vec(0, 0)
    self.pos = vec(x, y) * TILESIZE
    self.last_shot = 0
    self.health = 100

def update(self):
    self.rotate()
    self.get_keys()
    self.pos += self.vel * dt
    self.rect.center = self.pos

def rotate(self):
    _, self.angle = (pg.mouse.get_pos() - self.pos).as_polar()
    self.image = pg.transform.rotozoom(self.orig_img, self.angle, 1)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

def get_keys(self):
    self.vel = vec(0, 0)
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pg.K_LEFT] or keys[pg.K_a]:
        self.vel.x = -PLAYERSPEED
    if keys[pg.K_RIGHT] or keys[pg.K_d]:
        self.vel.x = PLAYERSPEED
    if keys[pg.K_UP] or keys[pg.K_w]:
        self.vel.y = -PLAYERSPEED
    if keys[pg.K_DOWN] or keys[pg.K_s]:
        self.vel.y = PLAYERSPEED
    if self.vel.x != 0 and self.vel.y != 0:
        self.vel *= 0.7071
    if keys[pg.K_SPACE]:
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_shot > BULLET_RATE:
            self.last_shot = now
            self.shoot()

def shoot(self):
    dir = vec(1, 0).rotate(self.angle)
    bullet = Bullet(self.pos, dir)
    all_sprites.add(bullet)
    bullets.add(bullet)
```

And here for camera and implementing camera in my game loop:

```
class Camera:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.camera = pg.Rect(0, 0, width, height)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def apply(self, entity):
        return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        x = -target.rect.x + int(WIDTH / 2)
        y = -target.rect.y + int(HEIGHT / 2)

        # limit scrolling to map size
        x = min(0, x)  # left
        y = min(0, y)  # top
        x = max(-(self.width - WIDTH), x)  # right
        y = max(-(self.height - HEIGHT), y)  # bottom
        self.camera = pg.Rect(x, y, self.width, self.height)
```

Inside game loop:

```
for sprite in all_sprites:
    screen.blit(sprite.image, camera.apply(sprite))

all_sprites.update()
camera.update(player)
```

I have read from other posts about making the mouse pos from screen cords to world cords, but I can't figure out how I would do that in my case...

Answer (score 0):

The angle of the image is calculated with the following line of code:

> ```py
> _, self.angle = (pg.mouse.get_pos() - self.pos).as_polar()
> ```

`pg.mouse.get_pos()` is a screen coordinate. So the code will only work if `self.pos` is also a screen coordinate.
If `self.pos` is a coordinate in the world, you need to calculate the position relative to the screen.

Pseudo code:

```py
screen_pos = self.pos - camera.camera.topleft
_, self.angle = (pg.mouse.get_pos() - screen_pos).as_polar()
```

Comment: @MadsKristianNylund Try `camera.camera.topleft`. However you cannot copy/paste this code. This is pseudo code. I cannot see your complet code, so I cannot provode a perfect solution. I can just make suggestions.

Comment: I tried that, no errors this time. But the rotation is still not working. Here is a link to the code, if you woudn't mind looking over it?:) https://github.com/MadsNyl/shooter

Comment: @MadsKristianNylund I'm sorry, but I don't have much time. Anyway it is not intended to provide a link to external resources. Please note Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. Stack Overflow is more about answering general questions and less about solving problems in specific code. Apart from this, the code in the repository is incomplete. Even if I wanted to, I couldn't debug it.

Comment: @MadsKristianNylund At first glance, however, it seems that the sign of the camera position is inverted. Thus try: `screen_pos = self.pos + camera.camera.topleft`